# AngularJS: Multiple async calls - how to

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

**Sample**

Please consider this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/egXWqzJuBREybNqs8WBn?p=preview).

**Background**

The Plunk is a seriously simplified sample of what I need to do. Basically I need to get a person record with validation result included. This result will also include class information, so that the controller can assign proper styling to indicate mandatory status (or not).

**The issue**

The most important function in the sample is this one, the self.Get will use the validation logic and result a result.

```
self.Get('0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e').then(function(result){
  $scope.person = result.person;

  $scope.validationResult = result.ValidateResult;
});
```

As you can see (because the form has correct values) $scope.person is loaded correctly, the $scope.validationResult however is not.

**The question**

I suspect there's a timing issue with the consecutive async calls, how can I fix this Plunk so that everything works correctly?

Nesting async calls in each other would be 'one' solution, I guess, but given the number of calls being made, that would not solve everything and the code would become highly unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple async calls I would suggest to use array of promises:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(service1.get(...))
promises.push(service2.get(...))
promises.push(service3.get(...))

return $q.all(promises);
```

Comment: How can I solve dependencies in this setup? I mean,

self.LoadPersonDetailProxy needs person,
validationService.ValidateAsync needs personDetailProxy.

Comment: service1.get(...).then(service2.get).then(service3.get)

Comment: Isn't there a better option than nesting? And, doesn't this also break the need for an array?

Comment: @Spikee: That's not nesting. It's chaining - the solution to nesting (why promises were created in the first place). Nesting is `get(get(get(get())))`

Comment: Ok, but it still makes the code hard to read if you have to do it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So, how do I convert the following code to use chaining, while keeping all dependencies intact?:

```
self.Get = function (personId) {
    // 1. Init
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var asyncCallsResult = {};

    // 2. Get person
    var person = self.GetTestPerson();
    asyncCallsResult.person = person;

    self.LoadPersonDetailProxy(person).then(function(personDetailProxy) {
        $scope.personDetailProxy = personDetailProxy;
    });

    validationService.ValidateAsync($scope.personDetailProxy).then(function (validateResult) {
        asyncCallsResult.ValidateResult = validateResult;
    });

    defer.resolve(asyncCallsResult);

    return defer.promise;
}
```